# Why am I getting "unbound variable or constructor" in my SML program

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have written a method to return the first element in a list that satisfies a function (passed in via currying). The function returns NONE or SOME depending on whether or not the element satisfies a condition.  I'm using Pattern Matching
However, I'm getting the dreaded error:
Error: unbound variable or constructor: my_function

I'm new to SML and one of the hardest things I find is understanding the error messages.  From previous experience with the message, I would think the problem is that my_function never returns, but I'm having trouble seeing the logic problem here. Can someone take a quick look and tell me the problem?  Is the problem that I'm raising an error when there is no element that satisfies the input function f?

I'm interested in what's wrong and perhaps more importantly, is there any way to get more information when you see this sort of error?

```
val  my_function = fn f => fn lst =>  (* Notice currying *)
  case lst of
      [] => raise NoAnswer  (* Get here is nothing in lst saf

    | x::xs => case f(x) of NONE => ( my_function f xs)
                 | SOME y  =>  x 

 val test = my_function(fn x => if x < 3 then SOME x else NONE) [1,2,3,4] = 2
```

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a function with the `val` keyword, the function can't be defined recursively. Hence, the problem is here:

```
... NONE => ( my_function f xs) ...
```

You can say that you want the function to be defined recursively by adding the `rec` keyword to the declaration.

```
val rec my_function = fn f => fn list => ...
```

Alternatively, the `fun` keyword is syntactic sugar for `val rec`. `fun` also includes nice syntactic sugar for currying:

```
fun my_function f lst = (* This is equivalent to your first line *)
```

Sometimes you still want to use just the `val` keyword and not `val rec`. For instance,

```
val f = fn x => x + 3
val f = fn y => f y + 4 (* f here refers to the previous declaration of f *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I didn't know that about val and not being able to call recursively.  I replaced val with fun and get errors:  Error: can't find function arguments in clause
and Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch].  Perhaps I really do have a logic error now.  I'll check into it.

Comment: Is the "raise NoAnswer" causing problems?  The idea is to return the first element from the list that safisfies the function f else throw an exception.  Can you not return an exception?

Comment: If you use `fun` instead of `val rec`, you must write `fun my_function f lst = ...` instead of `fun my_function = fn f => fn lst => ...`

Comment: Wow!  Works. Thanks!  Marking as answer.  But if you have a second... how are you able to say what the problem is from the error descriptions?  The first error, "Unbound constructor..." doesn't really suggest "can't do recursion with val".  And that second error, "right-hand-side of clause.." doesn't really say you can't use fn f => fn lst.  Again, I find this interpretation of errors the most difficult thing with ML.  thanks again.

Comment: http://www.smlnj.org/doc/errors.html provides examples of situations where you would receive error messages. For the second error, the more relevant message was "can't find function arguments in clause".